# Override default CreateController in side MyModule in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, overrides, extensions

I need to Override
Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php

Step 1:-  I write in etc/config.xml

```
<admin>
   <routers>
       <adminhtml>
           <args>
               <modules>
                   <Mycompany_Mymodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml</Mycompany_Mymodule>
               </modules>
           </args>
       </adminhtml>
   </routers>
```

Step 2:- I put CreateController.php file on this location
/var/www/magento/app/code/community/Mycompany/Mymodule/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order

Step 3: I did changes in controller class name

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController
{ }
```

I am unable to override by this implementation. Please, Help me to override this controller.

Comment: did you add the file `app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Mymodule.xml`?

Comment: and do you get an error or just nothing happens?

Comment: Yes, I added and it is working.

Comment: @DavidManners I am not getting any error in log file. It just nothing happens. I have checked default CreateController.php is loading.

Comment: @PranavKrMurari you controller has no code in it so it will simply call the original controller or am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidManners I am trying to call simply construct protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setUsedModuleName('Mage_Sales');

        // During order creation in the backend admin has ability to add any products to order
        Mage::helper('catalog/product')->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
      Mage:: log("Custom");
    }

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the admin controller class you are extending off - it doesn't get auto included in controllers:

```
include_once("Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php");
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but still no luck.

Comment: Double check all of your syntax, my guess is something is not declared correctly or you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @All Thanks for your valuable suggestion. There was class conflict. CreateController was called in another also. I have resolved my issue.